# Data type mismatch in insert statement

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to do an insert statement into SQL, but get the following error:

> there's an error data type mismatch in criteria expression

This is my query:

```
string Query = "INSERT INTO [laptop table]
(Name,Serial,Charger,Colour,Notes,Exist) 
VALUES
('" + this.nametxt.Text + "','" + 
    this.serialtxt.Text + "','" + 
    this.chargertxt.Text + "','" + 
    this.colourtxt.Text + "','" + 
    this.notestxt.Text + "','" +
    this.Exist.Checked.ToString() + "');";
```

Does anybody know what causes this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [ask] and [faq]. We won't be able to help you if you do not elaborate on what your problem ist.

Comment: Oww my eyes - Yuck! If only the code used [*placeholders*](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp.html), this problem *wouldn't even exist*! Hence my recommendation is to use placeholders. Inspecting the *actual* string value would reveal the SQL syntax/typing issue and it could be played with in SSMS or whatever.

Comment: one of the attributes of `laptop table` might have a non-textual data type. look at `Serial`.

Answer (score 3):

ASSUMPTION: Exists column is a boolean that you want to store.

The problem is that the last column is a `bit` and not a `string` .

There are a few things wrong with this but that is the main reason why it is not working.

The other major issue is that you are leaving yourself open so SQL Injection attacks. Have a look at paramertising your input to protect yourself.

You can have a look at parametising your query here

[parameterized sql query - asp.net / c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600179/parameterized-sql-query-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: I was the downvoter but I see that you have removed the code with the string concatenation. Now if you add an example of a parametrized query that would be perfect

Answer (score 1):

please check the data type of your table.

if Exist column is bit type then your Query should be like

string Query = "INSERT INTO [laptop table] (Name,Serial,Charger,Colour,Notes,Exist) VALUES('" + this.nametxt.Text + "','" + this.serialtxt.Text + "','" + this.chargertxt.Text + "','" + this.colourtxt.Text + "','" + this.notestxt.Text + "','" +  Convert.ToBoolean(this.Exist.Checked) + "');";