# While input of date - literal does not match format string

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle

I have this line of code in asp.net through which inserting date into a table

```
CMPI_EFF_DATE = cc.GetDataSet("SELECT TRM_EFF_STDT as TRM_EFF_STDT FROM TRM_MST WHERE TRM_CODE = " + ddlTrm.SelectedValue + "").Tables[0].Rows[0]["TRM_EFF_STDT"].ToString(),
```

and i am using oracle database . but while inserting data into it it show's an error

```
 literal does not match format string
```

Comment: You should be using [parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600179/parameterized-sql-query-asp-net-c-sharp), which would probably solve this issue in addition to closing a potential SQL Injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `ddlTrm.SelectedValue` string value? if it's true, I thing you should put value in quotes like this

```
"'" + ddlTrm.SelectedValue+"'"
```

Full example:

```
CMPI_EFF_DATE = cc.GetDataSet("SELECT TRM_EFF_STDT as TRM_EFF_STDT FROM TRM_MST WHERE TRM_CODE = '" + ddlTrm.SelectedValue+"'").Tables[0].Rows[0]["TRM_EFF_STDT"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong here `ddlTrm.SelectedValue + "")`

It should be `ddlTrm.SelectedValue )`

```
CMPI_EFF_DATE = cc.GetDataSet("SELECT TRM_EFF_STDT as TRM_EFF_STDT FROM TRM_MST WHERE TRM_CODE = " + ddlTrm.SelectedValue).Tables[0].Rows[0]["TRM_EFF_STDT"].ToString(),
```

Comment: Still ... same error  `literal does not match format string`

Comment: if the selected value is string and trm_code is string then you need to use`'` in your query.